# 'names' attribute must be the same length as vector

Tags: r, plot, attributes, glm, lm

I am trying to plot my regression analyses

I have created a glm model to determine the effect of agriculture on species richness of birds.

this is my code for my glm:

```
spec_rich_final <- glm(species_richness ~ (trans_forest * fert_total) + 
agri + I(trans_agri^2) + diversity + (I(diversity^2)) + (I(trans_forest^2) 
* fert_total) + trans_semi_natural + bio1, poisson(link = "log"), 
data=data_transformed)
```

then this is my code for plotting:

```
effect_plot(spec_rich_final, pred = agri, interval = TRUE, 
partial.residuals = TRUE)
```

I then get this error:

```
Error in names(o) <- rownames(attr(terms(formula), "factors")) : 
  'names' attribute [10] must be the same length as the vector [8]
```

Can anyone help? no idea what it means by attribute 10 or vector 8??

Comment: The error is about lengths not matching. The names attribute has a length of 10, but the vector you've tried to assign to it has a length 8. Beyond that, we can't run your code without a sample of data that replicates this

Comment: @camille what is a length though? is there a way I can attach my code? Also - when I run the plot for plotting raw data it works fine but not for residuals. In a paper would it be better to show a plot of raw data or residuals do you know?

Comment: The length of a vector. Like the number of things in that vector. As for what you need in a paper: that totally depends on context, subject, where it's being published, requirements of analysis, type of analysis...so, no clue. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a good R post. You can (and should) post code needed to help debug

Comment: What package does `effect_plot` come from? Perhaps `str(spec_rich_final)` and `str(agri)` would be sufficient. But as chamille said, their lengths differ for sure and the problems is probably somewhere else. A step-by-step rubber duck debugging is in order.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because you are using:

```
glm(species_richness ~ ... + agri + I(trans_agri^2) + diversity + (I(diversity^2)))
```

Instead use

```
glm(species_richness ~ ... + poly(agri, 2) + poly(diversity, 2))
```

In the effect_plot function add:

```
data=data_transformed
```